# (Small) Java server side application fails to receive DatagramPackets

Tags: java, azure, udp, port, datagram

I have a Linux Microsoft Azure VM that is running Java JDK 7 "Server" (Using SSH to connect)

My computer (Mac OSX) is running Java JDK 8 "Server"

The message client is compiled and run on my computer and the server is run and compiled on my vm.  I have configured the ports xxx2 and xxx3 to UDP.

Server Code:

```
public class server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int OutPort = xxx2;
        int InPort = xxx3;
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        System.out.println("LOCALHOST:" + InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        InetAddress users[] = new InetAddress[1000];
        DatagramSocket dataIn = new DatagramSocket(OutPort);
        DatagramSocket dataOut = new DatagramSocket(InPort);
        DatagramPacket dataIncoming = new DatagramPacket(data, 2048);
        int userNum = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                dataIn.receive(dataIncoming);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            String message = dataIncoming.getData().toString();
            if (message.startsWith("login")) {
                users[userNum] = dataIncoming.getAddress();
                System.out.println("NEW USER:" + dataIncoming.getAddress().toString() + ", ADDED AS:" + users[userNum]);
                userNum++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= userNum; i++) {
                dataOut.send(new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), 2048, users[i], InPort));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
public class message {
    public String username;
    public int OutPort = xxx2;
    public int InPort = xxx3;
//    xxx2 out, xxx3 in (default for testing the opposite).
    final InetAddress address;
    message() throws UnknownHostException {
//        Create the variables.
        InetAddress addresses[] = null;
        address = InetAddress.getByName("xxxxx.cloudapp.net");
        addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("xxxxx.cloudapp.net");
//        Create the colors.
        Color background = new Color(141,234,184);
//        Create the window.
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Java Message");
        window.setSize(600,400);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
//        Create the title.
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Xxxxx's Java Messaging System");
        title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        title.setOpaque(true);
        title.setBackground(background);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        window.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//        Create the text output.
        JTextArea content = new JTextArea();
        content.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        content.setEditable(false);
        window.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(content);
        window.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//        Create the info panel.
        JTextArea info = new JTextArea();
        info.setFont(new Font("Menlo", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        startup(info, address, addresses);
        window.add(info, BorderLayout.EAST);
//        Create username dialog.
        JDialog usernameWindow = new JDialog();
        usernameWindow.setTitle("Username setup");
        usernameWindow.setSize(300,200);
        usernameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        usernameWindow.setVisible(true);
//        Create username title.
        JLabel loginTitle = new JLabel("Enter a username:");
        loginTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        usernameWindow.add(loginTitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//        Create username input.
        JTextField usernameInput = new JTextField();
        usernameInput.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        usernameWindow.add(usernameInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        usernameInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (usernameInput.getText().length() >= 8) {
                    errorDialog("Username too long, must be 8 characters or less!");
                } else {
                    username = usernameInput.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
                    content.append(":Logged in as:" + username + "\n");
                    sendMessage("login", username, address);
                    usernameWindow.dispose();
                }
            }
        });
//        Create the text input.
        JTextField messageInput = new JTextField();
        window.add(messageInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        reciveMessages(content);
        messageInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                sendMessage(username, messageInput.getText(), address);
                messageInput.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new message();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR:" + e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void startup(JTextArea content, InetAddress ip, InetAddress ips[]) {
        InetAddress local = null;
        try {
            local = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        content.append("SERVER IP(s):\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) content.append(ips[i].getHostAddress() + "\n");
        content.append("USING:\n" + ip.getHostAddress() + "\n\n");
        content.append("LOCALHOST:\n" + local.getHostAddress() + "\n");
    }
    public void sendMessage(String username, String message, InetAddress address) {
        byte data[] = new byte[2048];
        char usernameChar[] = username.toCharArray();
        char messageChar[] = message.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < usernameChar.length; i++) data[i] = (byte)usernameChar[i];
        data[usernameChar.length + 1] = (byte)':';
        for (int c = 0; c < messageChar.length; c++) data[usernameChar.length + c + 2] = (byte)messageChar[c];
        try {
            DatagramSocket outSocket = new DatagramSocket(OutPort);
            DatagramPacket dataOut = new DatagramPacket(data, 2048, address, InPort);
            outSocket.send(dataOut);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public void reciveMessages(JTextArea content) {
        new Thread("PortListener") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    byte inData[] = new byte[2048];
                    DatagramSocket inSocket = new DatagramSocket(InPort);
                    DatagramPacket dataIn = new DatagramPacket(inData, 2048);
                    while (true) {
                        inSocket.receive(dataIn);
                        content.append(new String(dataIn.getData(), 0, dataIn.getLength()));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
    public void errorDialog(String cause) {

    }
}
```

PROBLEM: I run the Server code on the VM and the console never returns "NEW USER:" and none of the messages are going through.

I am completely new to java networking and made this after finishing a Java guide book chapter (The book is published by Oracle) and I needed some guidance on how to get this to work.

I have no idea if it is a simple error or the whole idea and theory is wrong.

MY THEORIES:

1. The server is incorrectly listening for the packets.
2. The client and the server data[] sizes are different.
3. The IP address of the server is incorrect (ex: missing internal IP) and I need to use a SocketAddress.

WHAT I KNOW:

I have made a version of this program where I compiled it and then recompiled it with the ports switched (so the outgoing became the incoming data) and ran both on my computer and the system worked fine.

Comment: I have been using java long seeing as I am still in high school and have not had that mush time around computers.  So please excuse me for dumb or simple errors.

Comment: Your server checks if the datagram starts with "login". The datagram you send doesn't start with "login".

Comment: @immibis once the user creates their username the system sends a message that starts with "login" (see ln 83)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after having gone through your code, I've made a working version. Here's what you need to edit and why(some of these may be unnecessary but this is what made it work for me):

I may have gotten a bit off with line numbers as I added some printing and comments to help me understand the code. Comment if I left out a fix/didn't explain something clearly.

Server Client:

At line 9, you don't need to specify a port for the outbound socket as that is specified in the packets.

```
DatagramSocket dataOut=new DatagramSocket();
```

At line 18 I'm not sure what you hoped to accomplish with calling the toString() method of an array, but you should convert a byte array back to a string like so:

```
String message = new String(dataIncoming.getData());
```

At line 24 you're going up to userNum, but userNum is the index of the next position of the array to be filled, so there's nothing there.
Change it to less than

```
for(int i=0;i<userNum;i++)
```

Message Client:

line 58: the toString() is redundant on a String

```
username=usernameInput.getText().toUpperCase();
```

line 107: Just like server, you don't need to declare port since that's done in the packet

```
DatagramSocket outSocket=new DatagramSocket();
```

Line 108: Since you're sending the data out to the port that the server is listening on(the outport), you should be sending to outport, not inport

```
DatagramPacket dataOut=new DatagramPacket(data,2048,address,OutPort);
```

Finally, line 123: I see what you were trying to do, but that will still give you a String with length 2048 and a lot of unreadable characters. Also, the line will not be terminated. Use trim() to reduce to the text and \n to terminate line.

```
content.append(new String(dataIn.getData()).trim()+"\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! I making edit and compiling right now.  Al though I am confused on Line 24 edit because your statement contradicts your edit.

Comment: Typo sorry I'll fix it

Comment: I have tried all your fixes, the server is still not receving the data

Comment: I hosted the server on a computer and ran the chat client on the same computer, then connected to myself. Have you tried doing that?